# Need help regarding IPN and paypal payment page

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm working on a website where the users can create listings like in a regular classifieds website.

My concern is that if a user wants to feature his listing on the website, he has to make a payment via Paypal (IPN). The problem is that when the user completes the payment, the paypal payment confirmation page will give the user 2 links at the bottom of the confirmation page. The first one is "return to your website" and the second one is "view your paypal account".

If the user clicks the first link it will trigger the featured option and make his listing featured. However if he clicks the second link the user will be sent to his paypal account and will not trigger the featured option.

My concern is that users who will click the second link will pay however will not get the service they paid for. This portion of the website was done by my developer and he said that it would only work if the user clicks the "return on your website" link.

Would you guys have any suggestions or help on how to resolve this? If Paypal did not show the second link it would resolve this pb.

Answer (score 0):

That's what IPN is for. If you enable it, PayPal will send you a payment notification. You should enable the feature for the user when you get the money, regardless of what the user navigates to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Will look into this deeper

Comment: Note that this is as much a business issue as a technical issue. You don't provide the goods until you receive the money. PayPal also tells if if the payment got cancelled, reversed, act., when you should disable the feature.